# Increasing value of PHP variable with onclick function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables

I have a variable `$count = 10;`that I want to increase by 10 each time a user clicks `<a id="load-more" href="#">Load more</a>`

I have tried setting this up with onclick, variable equations and functions but I cannot seem to get it to increase.

Ultimately, I want the `$count = 10;` to increase to `$count = 20;` and so forth each time the user clicks.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're looking for AJAX. It will allow client-side request to update/do something with server-side variables.

Comment: PHP is server side, javascript is client side. The only way to increase the PHP $count variable is to load a PHP page. This can be done with a reload or an AJAX call. The variable will also need to be persistent somehow.

Comment: I am not an AJAX or javascript programmer so any input of how to structure it would be very helpful.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ and http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, you're looking for a solution that makes use of AJAX. Something like this:

On the client:

```
$('#load-more').click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://example.com/stuff.php",
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
      // Success! Do something with `data` here:
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // Error! You should probably display an error message here:
    }
  })
})
```

On the server (stuff.php):

```
<?php
  $value = retrieveValue(); // Replace this with whatever means you are using to get the persisted value.
  $value += 10; // Increment the value by 10 each time.
  saveValue($value); // Replace this with whatever means you are using to save the persisted value.
?>
```

Keep in mind that in order to keep the value incrementing with each request you will have to persist the value in PHP by some means (database, session, file, etc.).

You will also need to load JQuery libs in your HTML file to use the above JavaScript code.

Comment: for me, it is better to increment this on javascript then post it. In that way, no need for database or session to persist the data. but of course, depending on what he intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change PHP variable's value (server side) by JavaScript (client side).
You can define a JavaScript variable and initialize it using PHP. But after that you can work only with your JavaScript variable.

```
<script>
var jsVar = <?php echo $phpVar; ?>;
jsVar++;
</script>
```

This is the way. For more information, the above code is sending PHP variable value to JavaScript(and the conversely is not possible).

- You can also send a JavaScript variable's value to a PHP script using AJAX commands.

And if you want to use AJAX command, you can do it via pure JavaScript or using jQuery or other libraries. jQuery usage is easier but you need to load the library. I do prefer pure JavaScript AJAX. Here is an example:

```
<script>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'php_script.php');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        // do something
    }
};
xhr.send('value=' + jsVar);
</script>
```

And you can use value as `$_POST['value']` in php_script.php file.

Answer (score -1):

Here it is.

`<input type="number" value="10" id="data">
<a id="load-more" href="#" onClick="increment()">Load more</a>`

`<script>
    function increment(){
        var count = parseInt(document.getElementById("data").value);
        count = count+=10;
        document.getElementById("data").value = count
        $.post('backend.php?count='+$("#data").val(),function(val){//alert});
    }
</script>`

Comment: This is not what the OP wants. He wants a PHP variable to be incremented, not a JavaScript variable.

Comment: @docksteaderluke we know thats not posible, only javascript can do that, can you give him a php alone?